# Max-min assignment problem

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima

I've tackled a discrete optimization problem which seems a bit hard to solve:

Assume that we have N resources that we need to assign to N workers. Each worker $i$ gets a reward of ${R_{ij}}$ if assigned to resource $j$, and each worker is only assigned to one resource.

My question is, is there a way to assign those resource such that we can maximize the minimum reward obtained ?

I've been thinking about the Hungarian Algorithm, but it seems to me that it only tends to maximize the sum of Rewards obtained by all workers instead of Maximizing the minimum reward obtained.

Thanks!